# Hammer js not working on windows phone 8

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, touch, swipe, hammer.js

Hammer.js is not working on windows phone 8.  I am testing on lumia 520. no tests give in hammer js are not working on this device. They are working fine on IE10 of windows 8 machine.
would you please help me with this.
Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: The events in latest version of hammer js are broke in windows phone 8. I read it later in github bugslist. So i reverted back to previous version. no issues now. Thanks

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, you can post it as an answer and accept it yourself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue with touch events in windows phone 8 with the latest build of hammer js. so i reverted my code back to previous version where it is working fine.

Comment: Please consider specifying what version was broken and which version worked. We could look at timelines relative to when this answer was posted, but having it in the answer could save users time.